# Which language is crossplatform and has no dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, cross-platform

Looking to know which language has no dependences (sort of like Java can run on crossplatform better than C# and C++ can have no dependencies while I think Java can't).

Answer (score 0):

Xojo fits the bill. Cross-platform to Windows, MacOS, Linux, Raspberry Pi and its apps are native and stand-alone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any other more popular languages? I heard Golang has no dependencies?